# Identify a comic where Scrooge McDuck was protected against a beam because he went swimming in his money

Tags: story-identification, comics, disney, ducktales, donald-duck

I remember reading a Donald Duck magazine or comic once (at least a decade ago, but the comic was already old by then) where Scrooge McDuck had built resistance against some kind of radiation or ray weapon because swimming in his money all his life added a protective layer of gold dust to his feathers. However, I cannot remember the type of radiation or weapon it was protecting against. I also cannot remember whether this was explained in the beginning of the comic (followed by a long string of attempts to get him to lose this gold dust by the villain of the week) or at the end of the comic as a way to explain a deus ex machina in the finale of the comic.

What was Scrooge McDuck protected against by his gold dust layer?

Comment: Feel free to manage the tags on this question. I have no idea which ones to use, and I don't know if the current tag is accurate enough.

Comment: Now, while Duck Tales is on-topic, I don't know if everything Donald Duck related counts as on-topic. Maybe take this to meta before asking this question. (you can always self-delete and undelete)

Comment: @Edlothiad there is precedent for Donald Duck being on topic: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52872/how-wealthy-is-uncle-scrooge-in-the-don-rosa-carl-barks-universe is a question from 2014 with positive reception and no discussion whether it's on-topic, and it explicitly refers to the Rosa/Barks universe.

Comment: There are is in fact more than one question. So be it. However the tag to use seems to be `disney` not `donald-duck`. I will let you decide whether you want to make this change. I still recommend you post on meta to get a proper consensus (preferably for a genre rather than just these specific books) so we can cite that next time.

Comment: @Edlothiad I created the meta on it. We'll see how it's received.

Comment: [The relevant meta is here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11528/68872) I've answered your meta trying to look at previous metas and at the wider topic of Disney Comics.

Comment: So what you're saying is that South Park was not being original with [Tonsil Trouble](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Tonsil_Trouble) :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is Uncle Scrooge #08, [The Mysterious Stone Ray](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/uncle-scrooge-8-the-mysterious-stone-ray/4000-160555/)

[image]

The device was a petrification ray, developed to defend the island by a Professor from Duckburg trying to perfect a recipe for fumeless cabbages

[image]